# Lua splitting a string without separators

Tags: string, lua, split

Is there an easy way to split a string like this:

```
M34a79 or M2ab943 or M4c4
```

into

```
M,34,a,79 or M,2,ab,943 or M,4,c,4
```

without any separators?

Comment: Leave the question as originally asked and add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a pair of gsub calls:

```
x = "M34a79 or M2ab943 or M4c4"

x, _ = x:gsub( "(%d)(%a)", "%1,%2" )
x, _ = x:gsub( "(%a)(%d)", "%1,%2" )

print( x )
```

> M,34,a,79 or M,2,ab,943 or M,4,c,4

Might not work in all cases, but does work on your example.

Comment: Yes, it works! :) Is it possible to store each of these values in variables?

Comment: Would you want it to be a table of them, like { "M", "34", "a", "79" }, { "M", "2", "ab", "943" }, { "M", "4", "c", "4" } ?

Comment: You don't need the `_`, just `x = x:gsub( "(%d)(%a)", "%1,%2" )` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind using the [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/)
library:

```
local lpeg            = require "lpeg"
local C, Ct, P, R     = lpeg.C, lpeg.Ct, lpeg.P, lpeg.R
local lpegmatch       = lpeg.match

local extract
do
  local digit     = R"09"
  local lower     = R"az"
  local comma     = P","
  local space     = P" "
  local schema    = Ct(   C(P"M")
                        * (digit^1 / tonumber)
                        * C(lower^1)
                        * (digit^1 / tonumber))
  local extractor = Ct((schema + 1)^0)
  extract = function (str)
    return lpegmatch (extractor, str)
  end
end
```

This will match all sequences of characters of the input
that consist of (in that order)

- the letter `M`,
- a sequence of 1 or more decimal digits,
- a sequence of 1 or more lowercase characters, and
- another sequence of 1 or more decimal digits.

When processing the input each match is put in a subtable,
the digits are converted to Lua numbers on the fly.
Since the question requested it, the leading `M` is included
in the entries.

Usage example:

```
local data = extract [[M34a79 or M2ab943 or M4c4]]

for i = 1, #data do
  local elm = data[i]
  print (string.format ("[%d] = { [1] = %q, [2] = %d, [3] = %q, [4] = %d },",
                        i, table.unpack (elm)))
end
```

Output:

```
[1] = { [1] = "M", [2] = 34, [3] = "a", [4] = 79 },
[2] = { [1] = "M", [2] = 2, [3] = "ab", [4] = 943 },
[3] = { [1] = "M", [2] = 4, [3] = "c", [4] = 4 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/04/16/lua-string-magic/

```
function string:split( inSplitPattern, outResults )
 ...
end

function val(x)
 x = x:gsub( "(%d)(%a)", "%1,%2" )
 x = x:gsub( "(%a)(%d)", "%1,%2" )

 Table = string.split(x,",")
 for i = 1, #Table do
   print( Table[i] ) 
 end
end

val("M3a5")
```

returns M 3 a 5